# Return only strings containing the number of hours using Regex (ex : 6h, 10h etc..)

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a query that returns only offer names containing the number of hours which is always written that way : 'digit+h' (ex : 6h, 10h etc..).

Here is a sample of my data :

| name | want_to_keep |
| --- | --- |
| Club Room with Health & Fitness access | No |
| Quadruple Room - 2 Double beds with Canal & Fluvial view | No |
| Habitación Doble/twin (3h máximo con check-in hasta las 11h) | Yes |
| Chambre Double "Baroque" (pour 10h à choisir dans la tranche horaire 11:00-16:00) | Yes |

The query returns nothing (Query produced no results) when I use `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '\d{1,2}h')`.

I tried the same expression on https://regexr.com/ on the following string and it seems ok :
"Habitación Doble/twin (3h máximo con check-in hasta las 11h)"

Comment: Use `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '\\d{1,2}h')`, you must use two backslashes to introduce a literal backslash into a string literal.

Comment: Maybe try `REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[0-9]{1,2}h')`?